# scrapy set the output file in code

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy with python

I can set the output json file in the cmd. but now I need to do that in code.

I tried this:

#### in the setting

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
 'jsonlines': 'scrapy.contrib.exporter.JsonLinesItemExporter',
}
FEED_FORMAT = 'jsonlines'
```

#### in the spider

```
def __init(self):
    settings.overrides['FEED_URI'] = 'output.json'
```

#### Note

I am developing a simple spider, so I just need Item Exporter, I don't need to create any item pipeline.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Ever figure this one out?

Comment: @Dagrooms yes I did, but actually I don't remember now because I ended up using a pipeline which writes the data to both JSON files in the file system and to a database on a cloud.

Comment: No problem, I got mine to work but I needed xml format anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found in an example on the Scrapy documentation. You can output to any format by writing the correct item pipeline, as follows:

```
import json

class JsonWriterPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open('items.jl', 'wb')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

Note that you must also include this pipeline in the default Scrapy project settings file.